# Response.Redirect not working after login to ASP.NET application

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have an asp.net textbox that is associated with autocomplete plugin. With that I have an extension to that plugin that autoSelects matching element when user, instead of selecting, just presses the tab key(blur). Below is the code for that. The problem is, first time blur event calls properly and the whole functionality works pretty fine. But second time, it does not work at all and it takes the value of 1st elements only.

The scenario in my case is like that. I have a text box and an add button. The textbox has autocomplete functionality where I type say gram and it populates all the units. As the gram is one of the unit in the datasource, pressing tab will accept that and when I press button, the text gram and its corresponding id will be added in a grid view. Then the textbox will become blank to add more such entries. The problem is, second time when I type something that matches to auto suggest menu item and press tab button, the blur event does not fire.

```
$(".ui-autocomplete-input").on("blur", function (event) {
                debugger;
                if ($(this)[0].id == $("#MainContent_TabContainer1_TabpanelNormal_textinput")[0].id) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "./AddRecipe.aspx/CheckIfRecipeTitleExists",
                        data: "{'title':'" + $('#' + 'MainContent_TabContainer1_TabpanelNormal_textinput').val() + "'}",
                        dataType: "text",
                        success: function (data) {
                            var oData = JSON.parse(data);
                            if (oData.d == "True") {
                                var textvalue = $('#MainContent_TabContainer1_TabpanelNormal_textinput').val();
                                alert("Recipe title " + textvalue + " already exists in our database. Please choose another title.");
                                $('#MainContent_TabContainer1_TabpanelNormal_textinput').val("");
                                $('#MainContent_TabContainer1_TabpanelNormal_textinput').focus();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                var autocomplete = $(this).data("autocomplete");
                if (autocomplete.selectedItem) { return; }
                var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i");
                autocomplete.widget().children(".ui-menu-item").each(function () {
                    var item = $(this).data("item.autocomplete");
                    if (matcher.test(item.label || item.value || item)) {
                        autocomplete.selectedItem = item;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                if (autocomplete.selectedItem) {
                    autocomplete._trigger("select", event, { item: autocomplete.selectedItem });
                }
            });
```

Please help me out understand why second time it does not fire.

Comment: A minimal example wih HTML, e.g. in a JSFiddle, would be useful for a problem like this

Answer (score 0):

Without a full example I can only guess based on the described behavior.

Try using a delegated event for blur instead:

```
$(document).on('blur', ".ui-autocomplete-input", function (event) {
```

This will run the jQuery selector after the event bubble up to a non-changing ancestor element, then applies the selector, then applies the function to any matching elements that caused the event. This works with dynamically changing DOM elements, so may solve your problem.

Comment: The code is quite big and I need to include a lot many things to show on fiddler. I will definitely try to set up some thing to show it on fiddler. By that time the question is very simple. Registering blur event handler with on, why it executes only first time and not the second time for the same control. The control gets its class names and other stuff like autocomplete menu dynamically through js. I tried the stuff you suggested but not working